# Looking for a wallpaper with paper airplanes

Tags: xubuntu, desktop-background

I'm looking for a wallpaper I used to have on my Xubuntu 14.04. I have no clue whether it was an Ubuntu one or not. It was blue, cartoon style, and it represented a band of paper airplanes about to attack some planet.

Could anyone help me to find it, please?

Comment: It reminds me of a standard debian wallpaper (debian being upstream of Ubuntu would likely have included it, but not had it a default background) titled "SpaceFun" alas it only has a single [cartoon style] rocket attacking a planet - found in `desktop-base` or `/usr/share/wallpapers/SpaceFun/` if installed.

Comment: Is desktop-base a package ?

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=desktop-base

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at it

Comment: fyi:  I love my wallpapers, and any *ubuntu release you can have all current & prior Ubuntu (and flavor) wallpapers, eg. me on my current 19.10 system I can get all wallpapers excluding 19.10 ones *as they haven't come out yet*  (when I mean all, I mean all flavors too!).  Myself I like aptitude & search for `-wallpaper` in the name - but use whatever you're comfortable with... https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=-wallpapers&searchon=names

Comment: @guiverc That should be an answer -- especially since it's still applicable to current versions.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at the list of 'standard' wallpaper presented to you when you [select wallpaper?](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/gs-change-wallpaper.html.en) If it is standard, then it should be in the same place as all the other standard options.

Comment: Yes I did. But it was on the 14.04, I'm presently running the 16.04 xubuntu. I don'r think it was a standard wallpaper though